# jq : how can i use the same search in other field without duplicate code?

Tags: json, duplicates, field, jq

i have this jq command :

```
cat myfile | jq  -c '{ 
    domain: .name, 
    results: .data | select(.answers != null) | .answers | map(.answer) | del(.[] | nulls) , 
    includes: .data | select(.answers != null) | .answers | map(.answer) | del(.[] | nulls) | map(match("rearch:(.*?)?[ \"]"; "ig").captures[0].string) | unique
    }'
```

to get this result :

```
{"domain":"blabla.com","results":["dorem rearch:blble.k iyh"],"includes":["blble.k"]}
{"domain":"bla.com","results":["koa rearch:ble.m","kl rearch:be.c lk"],"includes":["ble.m","be.c"]}
```

my **question** is : is there any way to `DRY` my command ?
i mean how can i get the *same result* without **duplicate** the part :

> .data | select(.answers != null) | .answers | map(.answer) | del(.[] |
> nulls)

how can i reuse the result of `results` feild ?
i have a really big file to work with so i don't want to waste time and resources.

Comment: Can you paste the input JSON and show the _exact_ output expected? It is tough to provide alternatives, but just looking at your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With a variable

```
< myfile.json jq  -c '
  (.data | select(.answers != null) | .answers | map(.answer) | del(.[] | nulls)) as $data
  | { 
    domain: .name, 
    results: $data,
    includes: $data | map(match("rearch:(.*?)?[ \"]"; "ig").captures[0].string) | unique
    }
'
```

### Without a variable

```
< myfile.json jq  -c '
  { domain: .name, 
    results: (.data | select(.answers != null) | .answers | map(.answer) | del(.[] | nulls)) }
  | .includes = (.results | map(match("rearch:(.*?)?[ \"]"; "ig").captures[0].string) | unique)
'
```